# SQL Server 2019 Error using LIMIT, OFFSET, FETCH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem using some function in SQL Server 2019.

The following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Konie
OFFSET 2;
```

returns:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>    Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 18363: )

Comment: `OFFSET` is an optional clause of `ORDER BY` as stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) so you can't specify it separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add order by

```
SELECT *
FROM Konie
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 2 ROWS;
```